libuuid lib on oracle linux
I'm working on a breatty old hybris project.
I have issue on initialize the platform: during ant initialize I have this error:
    [java] INFO  [main] [VjdbcServerWrapper] VJDBC server established successfully 
     [java] INFO  [main] [EHCacheRegion] EHCacheRegion adaptiveSearchCacheRegion, eviction policy LRU, size 2000
     [java] INFO  [main] [DefaultRMIRegistryService] Creating Registry on port 2198.
     [java] INFO  [main] [LocalRMISocketFactory] Creating server socket at '/127.0.0.1:2198'.
     [java] java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/marcodaniele.coppola/git/riello/riello-pim/bin/ext-integration/sap/core/sapcorejco/lib/linuxintel/libsapjco3.so: libuuid.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1937)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1820)
     [java]     at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:782)
     [java]     at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1098)
     [java]     at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.DefaultJCoRuntime.loadJCoLibrary(DefaultJCoRuntime.java:797)
     [java]     at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.DefaultJCoRuntime.registerNativeMethods(DefaultJCoRuntime.java:444)
     [java]     at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.JCoRuntime.registerNatives(JCoRuntime.java:1383)
     [java]     at com.sap.conn.rfc.driver.CpicDriver.<clinit>(CpicDriver.java:934)
     [java]     at com.sap.conn.rfc.engine.DefaultRfcRuntime.getVersion(DefaultRfcRuntime.java:36)
     [java]     at com.sap.conn.rfc.api.RfcApi.RfcGetVersion(RfcApi.java:236)

searching on internet I see that it's releated to libuuid lib.
Checking on my Oracle linux machine, I discovered that I have the library:
[root@localhost platform]# yum install libuuid
github_git-lfs                                                                                                                                                                                                425  B/s | 951  B     00:02    
github_git-lfs-source                                                                                                                                                                                         448  B/s | 951  B     00:02    
Package libuuid-2.37.4-15.0.1.el9.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
[root@localhost platform]# 

how can I resolve?
I runned the ant clean all and the ant initialize.
On windows machine (of my colleguees) looks fine.
